# How to show First name and last name in one row in WooCommerce emailing

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

WooCommerce emails showing billing & shipping address first name and last name in two separate lines. But I want to be shown in single line. Please anyone can help me. I can not able to find classes behind the hooks so that I can make edits.

Comment: Could you please add some example (code)?

Comment: Woocommerce/Settings/E-Mails. There you should have different types of email-templates. 
For example "New Order". Click on the name of the template or on "Manage/Edit". At the bottom there should be a HTML-Template-Section with a direcotry.
=> theme-child/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
This link might be helpfull: https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-customize-woocommerce-order-emails/